# IOS google maps Image data can't be NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

Launch Xcode and either open an existing project, or create a new project. If you're new to iOS, create a Single View Application, and disable Use Storyboards but ensure that Use Automatic Reference Counting is on.

Drag the `GoogleMapsM4B.framework` bundle into your project. When prompted, select Copy items if needed. Right-click `GoogleMapsM4B.framework` in your project, and select Show In Finder.

Drag the `GoogleMaps.bundle` from the Resources folder into your project. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group's folder is not selected.

Select your project from the Project Navigator, and choose your application's target. Open the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add the following frameworks:

```
Accelerate.framework AVFoundation.framework CoreBluetooth.framework CoreData.framework CoreGraphics.framework CoreLocation.framework CoreText.framework GLKit.framework ImageIO.framework libc++.dylib libicucore.dylib libz.dylib OpenGLES.framework QuartzCore.framework Security.framework SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the Build Settings tab.

Replace the default value of Architectures with armv7. In the Other Linker Flags section,

add `-ObjC`. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the 
Build Settings bar from Basic to All.

Once you have your API key, add it to your `AppDelegate.m` as follows.

Add the following import statement:

```
#import <GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h>
Add the following to your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, replacing YOUR_API_KEY with your API key:
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];

#import <GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation YourViewController {
  GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

// You don't need to modify the default initWithNibName:bundle: method.

- (void)loadView {
  // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
  // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                          longitude:151.20
                                                               zoom:6];
  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  self.view = mapView_;

  // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
  marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
  marker.title = @"Sydney";
  marker.snippet = @"Australia";
  marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

what ever in google i followed these all steps but i am getting these warring and not showing current location pin.

```
((null)) was false: Cannot find image polyline_colors_texture_dim
2015-12-19 15:18:22.961 [5954:60b] ((null)) was false: Image data can't be NULL.
2015-12-19 15:18:22.975 [5954:60b] ((null)) was false: Invalid texture state for routesDimTextureState.
2015-12-19 15:18:24.025 [5954:60b] ((null)) was false: Cannot find image GMSNavSprites-0-2x
2015-12-19 15:18:24.031 [5954:60b] ((null)) was false: Image data can't be NULL.
2015-12-19 15:18:24.039 [5954:60b] ((null)) was false: Cannot find image GMSNavNightModeSprites-0-2x
2015-12-19 15:18:24.044 [5954:60b] ((null)) was false: Image data can't be NULL.
```

and its not showing current location pin.please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
One of the idea I came up is to create a CGPath and stroke it with gradient every time when drawMapRect method been called, since the MKPolylineView is replaced by MKPlolylineRenderer in ios7.

I tried to implement this by subclassing a MKOverlayPathRenderer but I failed to pick out individual CGPath, then I find a mysterious method named-(void) strokePath:(CGPathRef)path inContext:(CGContextRef)context which sounds like what I need, but it will not be called if you don't call the super method when you override your drawMapRect.

thats what Im working out for now.

I'll keep trying so if I work out something I'll come back and update the answer.

=========UPDATE================================================

enter image description here

So that is what I'm worked out these days, I almost implemented the basic idea mentioned above but yes, I still cannot pick out an individual PATH according to specific mapRect, so I just draw all paths with gradient at the same time when the boundingBox of all paths intersects with current mapRect. poor trick, but work for now.

In the -(void) drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context method in render class, I do this:

CGMutablePathRef fullPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
BOOL pathIsEmpty = YES;

//merging all the points as entire path
for (int i=0;i< polyline.pointCount;i++){
    CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i]];
    if (pathIsEmpty){
        CGPathMoveToPoint(fullPath, nil, point.x, point.y);
        pathIsEmpty = NO;
    } else {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(fullPath, nil, point.x, point.y);
    }
}

//get bounding box out of entire path.
CGRect pointsRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(fullPath);
CGRect mapRectCG = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];
//stop any drawing logic, cuz there is no path in current rect.
if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(pointsRect, mapRectCG))return;

Then I split the entire path point by point to draw its gradient individually. note that the hues array containing hue value mapping each velocity of location.

for (int i=0;i< polyline.pointCount;i++){
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i]];
    ccolor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hues[i] saturation:1.0f brightness:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
    if (i==0){
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
    } else {
        CGPoint prevPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i-1]];
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
        CGFloat pc_r,pc_g,pc_b,pc_a,
        cc_r,cc_g,cc_b,cc_a;
        [pcolor getRed:&pc_r green:&pc_g blue:&pc_b alpha:&pc_a];
        [ccolor getRed:&cc_r green:&cc_g blue:&cc_b alpha:&cc_a];
        CGFloat gradientColors[8] = {pc_r,pc_g,pc_b,pc_a,
                                    cc_r,cc_g,cc_b,cc_a};

        CGFloat gradientLocation[2] = {0,1};
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGFloat lineWidth = CGContextConvertSizeToUserSpace(context, (CGSize){self.lineWidth,self.lineWidth}).width;
        CGPathRef pathToFill = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(path, NULL, lineWidth, self.lineCap, self.lineJoin, self.miterLimit);
        CGContextAddPath(context, pathToFill);
        CGContextClip(context);//<--clip your context after you SAVE it, important!
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientLocation, 2);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGPoint gradientStart = prevPoint;
        CGPoint gradientEnd = point;
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, gradientStart, gradientEnd, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);//<--Don't forget to restore your context.
    }
    pcolor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:ccolor.CGColor];
}

That is all the core drawing method and of course you need points, velocity in your overlay class and feed them with CLLocationManager.

the last point is how to get hue value out of velocity, well, I found that if hue ranging from 0.03~0.3 is exactly represent from red to green, so I do some proportionally mapping to hue and velocity.

last of the last, here you are this is full source of this demo:https://github.com/wdanxna/GradientPolyline

don't panic if can't see the line you draw, I just position the map region on my position


One of the idea I came up is to create a CGPath and stroke it with gradient every time when drawMapRect method been called, since the MKPolylineView is replaced by MKPlolylineRenderer in ios7.

I tried to implement this by subclassing a MKOverlayPathRenderer but I failed to pick out individual CGPath, then I find a mysterious method named-(void) strokePath:(CGPathRef)path inContext:(CGContextRef)context which sounds like what I need, but it will not be called if you don't call the super method when you override your drawMapRect.

thats what Im working out for now.

I'll keep trying so if I work out something I'll come back and update the answer.

=========UPDATE================================================

enter image description here

So that is what I'm worked out these days, I almost implemented the basic idea mentioned above but yes, I still cannot pick out an individual PATH according to specific mapRect, so I just draw all paths with gradient at the same time when the boundingBox of all paths intersects with current mapRect. poor trick, but work for now.

In the -(void) drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context method in render class, I do this:

CGMutablePathRef fullPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
BOOL pathIsEmpty = YES;

//merging all the points as entire path
for (int i=0;i< polyline.pointCount;i++){
    CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i]];
    if (pathIsEmpty){
        CGPathMoveToPoint(fullPath, nil, point.x, point.y);
        pathIsEmpty = NO;
    } else {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(fullPath, nil, point.x, point.y);
    }
}

//get bounding box out of entire path.
CGRect pointsRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(fullPath);
CGRect mapRectCG = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];
//stop any drawing logic, cuz there is no path in current rect.
if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(pointsRect, mapRectCG))return;

Then I split the entire path point by point to draw its gradient individually. note that the hues array containing hue value mapping each velocity of location.

for (int i=0;i< polyline.pointCount;i++){
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i]];
    ccolor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hues[i] saturation:1.0f brightness:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
    if (i==0){
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
    } else {
        CGPoint prevPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i-1]];
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
        CGFloat pc_r,pc_g,pc_b,pc_a,
        cc_r,cc_g,cc_b,cc_a;
        [pcolor getRed:&pc_r green:&pc_g blue:&pc_b alpha:&pc_a];
        [ccolor getRed:&cc_r green:&cc_g blue:&cc_b alpha:&cc_a];
        CGFloat gradientColors[8] = {pc_r,pc_g,pc_b,pc_a,
                                    cc_r,cc_g,cc_b,cc_a};

        CGFloat gradientLocation[2] = {0,1};
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGFloat lineWidth = CGContextConvertSizeToUserSpace(context, (CGSize){self.lineWidth,self.lineWidth}).width;
        CGPathRef pathToFill = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(path, NULL, lineWidth, self.lineCap, self.lineJoin, self.miterLimit);
        CGContextAddPath(context, pathToFill);
        CGContextClip(context);//<--clip your context after you SAVE it, important!
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientLocation, 2);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGPoint gradientStart = prevPoint;
        CGPoint gradientEnd = point;
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, gradientStart, gradientEnd, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);//<--Don't forget to restore your context.
    }
    pcolor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:ccolor.CGColor];
}

That is all the core drawing method and of course you need points, velocity in your overlay class and feed them with CLLocationManager.

the last point is how to get hue value out of velocity, well, I found that if hue ranging from 0.03~0.3 is exactly represent from red to green, so I do some proportionally mapping to hue and velocity.

last of the last, here you are this is full source of this demo:https://github.com/wdanxna/GradientPolyline

don't panic if can't see the line you draw, I just position the map region on my position
```